# Oracle Linux logon screen without login box

Tags: oracle-linux, oracle

today my Oracle Linux Server 7.3 (installed on a Proxmox VM) just shows a gray window, where normaly the login prompt would be. The gray background is the regular "noisy" Oracle Server 7 wallpaper. I tried using ctrl+alt+FX ... after some seconds the whole server reboots.

Pinging the machine does not work. Can't connect to the oracle server either.

Has anyone an idea what could be wrong?!

Edit: I managed to start a single user shell but have no idea where to start honestly.

Answer (score 0):

From the single user shell you could force a trace execution of the suspected "S" malfunctioning script under */etc/rc.d/rc*.d*  , i.e.

```
       ls /etc/rc.d/rc*.d/S*
```

, just to have a hint where things start to go wrong

This can be accomplished by changing, provisionaly, the following in the first line of the script

```
    #!/bin/sh
```

to become

```
     #!/bin/sh  -x
```